# Were the results of the gravity probe B according to what was expected?

Tags: geology

By using a gyroscope the curvature of space-time made by the earth was measured.

I know that gravity is not exactly the same everywhere on the earth because of density of the mass beneath it. Probably above the mountains gravity is a bit higher. Due to variation of matter in the earth there would be other differences.

But were the results of this experiment according to what was already known or did it give new information about the earth?

Comment: Please reference the study